# Как передать директорию с файлами на сервер по SSH?

Tags: golang

Как можно передать каталог с файлами на сервер по `SSH (html, css, js скрипты и т.д)`? Мне говорили что нельзя передавать каталоги с файлами по `SSH`. Создавать каталоги и загружать туда рекурсивно файлы не вариант так-как я не знаю какими будут файлы и каталоги. Не одной библиотеки я ещё не встречал которая смогла бы загружать каталоги с файлами по SSH, только файлы по одиночке. Подскажите что да как сделать, искал в интернете все без результатов, нашел библиотеку *https://github.com/bramvdbogaerde/go-scp*, но только может заливать файлы, а каталоги нет, хотя в исходном коде я нашел функцию по заливке каталогов, ну или она было просто так написана.

Comment: Tar + gzip/ bzip2 отправить и на месте untar. Должно сработать. (Не в тему для го).

Comment: лично не проверял но вот вроде как раз то что нужно https://github.com/hypersleep/easyssh

Comment: @biosckon неа, это тоже самое, только файлы копирует

Comment: На машине источник ‘tar cf’ затем копируете этот ‘tar’ файл с помощью ‘scp’ на удаленную машину. Далее посылаете команду с помощью ‘ssh’ для разархивирования ‘tar xf’ на удаленной машине.

Comment: Скорей всего это решается утилитой *scp* https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего всё это сделать bash скриптом будет проще :) но вот вариант...

1. https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/ для запуска `tar czf ....gz` вы получаете один tar файл с сохранением полной структуры каталогов и файлов. `z` ёще и сожмёт.
2. (опция) Если очень хочется всё на go то https://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/
3. https://github.com/bramvdbogaerde/go-scp отправляете этот один файл на удалённую машину.
4. http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-ssh-connection/ отпаравляете команду `tar xf ...` для разпаковки. [код](https://gist.github.com/svett/b7f56afc966a6b6ac2fc)
5. Удаляете tar архив на локальной машине.
6. Открываете пиво (опционально)